How to remove files older than 60 days using a batch file
I am trying to create a batch file to remove files older than 60 days from a specific folder.  I have tried a few of the suggestions here and the one below but none of them do anything.
$source = "C:\Users\CC\Documents\0Temp"
#files older than 60 days
$maxAge = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)
Get-ChildItem $source -File | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $maxAge } | Remove-Item -Force

Would appreciate any suggestions to correct this or another way of deleting the files.

No error casted ? Are at least some files filtered as complying the age limit ?

Does Get-ChildItem $source -File | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $maxAge } return anything? Does Get-ChildItem $source -File return anything? Try debugging pieces of it.

$source is the folder path. Underneath the folder, there might not be any files which are older than 60 days. Kindly check what is the return output of Get-ChildItem $source -File | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $maxAge } . If this is returning value, then only it will remove.
Also apply try /catch to have a better error handling

As aside, better do $maxAge = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60).Date so it will check the date as of midnight instead of the time you are currently running the script. Next, why in the title you talk about a batch script, where the code is obviously PowerShell. (you also tagged PowerShell)

I find that using the -WhatIf switch on commands like Remove-Item is very helpful until I know that the script will remove the correct items.

This script can solve your problem:
$PathToFolder = "C:\Example\Path"
$LimitTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)

# Delete the files based on the limit time
Get-ChildItem -Path $PathToFolder -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $LimitTime } | Remove-Item -Force

You will need to change the path of the folder you want to delete files older than 60 days.
Regards!
